# button invisible when add to linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show table and below that table i want to show button in center of the table layout, so i wrap the both in linear layout but now it doesn't display. please help me to solve the problem.
this is my xml layout file=-

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip" >
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=" Order " />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't use a RelativeLayout?

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item">
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemTable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dip" >
</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/itemTable"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text=" Order " />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

this way it should adapt nicely inside the layout.

If your problem is that you don't SEE the button,maybe your table is too big?You should make it smaller,or put everything inside a nice ScrollView

Comment: u r right i was wasting my time with that linear layout thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:orientation="vertical"` to your `LinearLayout`

Comment: @BrianWebster I was not requesting any clarification. Just trying to be polite. Anyway, hope re-framing the the sentence solves this.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. It is an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

add scrollView as parent:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dip" >
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=" Order " />
</LinearLayout>

</Scrollview>
```

Comment: u r right that i put that scrollview it displays the button to right of table layout but i actually want to show the button exactly centered below table layout. if i go to change to orientation of linear layout to vertical then it displays my button at correct position but it forces the tablelayout to change its orientation to vertical so im confused what to do?m

Comment: then do one thing, add linearlayout as parent of button. and for first linearlayout add attribute as `android:orientation="verticle"`

Answer (score 0):

add android:gravity = "center_horizontal" to the Linear Layout and set orientation of LinearLayout as Vertical.